# Search by 4 months ago on Membership

Tags: civimember, search

We have civi 5.53 and Wordpress.

I am wanting to deal with overdue memberships.  We have an end date of the last day of the month.  Start date doesn't work for us so using end date.

I can use the option for month before previous month to get all our 30 day overdues.  I would like to be able to find all those end dates for membership that are 3 months and 4 months over due.

I'm wanting this to be an automatic search - so whilst I can do this manually does anyone know how I could do this so that I can save a report with the criteria in for 3 months and 4 months ago?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using Search Kit?

[image]

Code:

```
[
  [
    "SavedSearch",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "Last_4_month",
          "label": "Last 4 month",
          "form_values": null,
          "mapping_id": null,
          "search_custom_id": null,
          "api_entity": "Membership",
          "api_params": {
            "version": 4,
            "select": [
              "id",
              "Membership_Contact_contact_id_01.display_name",
              "end_date"
            ],
            "orderBy": [],
            "where": [
              [
                "end_date",
                "<=",
                "now - 4 month"
              ]
            ],
            "groupBy": [],
            "join": [
              [
                "Contact AS Membership_Contact_contact_id_01",
                "LEFT",
                [
                  "contact_id",
                  "=",
                  "Membership_Contact_contact_id_01.id"
                ]
              ]
            ],
            "having": []
          },
          "expires_date": null,
          "description": null
        }
      ],
      "match": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```